# Rails Backups, rsnapshot, duplicity, crashplan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, backup

I was wondering what the best off-site solution for backing up a rails server on a budget is.  We currently have ~30 gb of data and expect it to grow to ~500gb in the next year.  We want to use rsnapshot, duplicity, or rdiff.  However, we want to do nightly backups and cost is an issue, we are on a low budget and cannot afford the ~$75 a month for S3 or ~$2600 as mentioned in previous questions.  What do other people do and how do you implement it.  I was thinking of using CrashPlan, but it seems like a mess to implement with rails.  Is it easily done?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the issues with rails and CrashPlan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just set up rsnapshot and it was pretty easy, i dont se why that couldnt be used on any system, then you just need to find a ftp backup service that fits your needs, i use rsyncpalace their biggest plan is 500 gb and they support rsnapshot and all the other common backup methods... (no im not a rep for them)